# Is there a way to pass multiple parameters in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

Is there a way to pass more than 1 Parameter in SQL Query?

**SQL Query with 1 Parameter.**

```
Select 
       cusode as ACCOUNT,
       cusfulname as NAME,
       cushomephone as PHONE,
       numcals as CALLCOUNT,
       firstcalltime as FIRSTCALL,
       durationhm as DURATION,
       address as ADDRESS,
       city as CITY
from table(os_un_etcist('4815044'))
```

How can I pass more than 1 parameter.
 e.g '4815044' and '415175'

Comment: is os_un_etcist a function? If so, perhaps modify it to allow a table of ids instead of just 1? (or create a new one that calls the original function)

Comment: man you are genius, I was thinking that as a table till now, I need to  find out what is inside that funtion, how can I do that? and no wonder I couldn't describe when I did `desc os_un_etcist`.

Comment: what IDE are you using? Toad, Sql Developer?

Comment: it confusing to explain, but I use SQLPLUS to test query and actual query will be interest in PC based software, and it will be publish to WEB.

Comment: you gonna make me do work here, huh?  Just kidding, but please download the FREE Sql Developer and then just browse the schema objects.  I'll post a quick answer soon.

Comment: I am happy to donate to you, I couldn't figure out why I can't access this table, I already have SQL Developer. I don't know how to set up. I will need to send spend time to set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify that function to allow for an array of ids, not just 1.  You can modify the existing, or create a new function that simply calls the original for each id and pipelines the data out.

To get the source of the function, you can do:

```
select line, text
from all_source
where name = 'MY_FUNCTION';
```

Or (Much better Option): Download [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) from Oracle (its free), and open the Functions folder for your connection.  Trust me, you'll want either this (or maybe Toad) moving forward.

Comment: you are great help thanks, do I just type `os_un_etcist` instead of 'MY_FUNCTION'?

Comment: I was able to get to into DB via SQL Developer, I see two funtions there, I don't see one I am using. :(

Comment: I am done thanks, I was able to find that funtion but it was some nasty codes over 200 lines, and it is out of my hand, but I was able to find table it is coming from thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if they have the same columns I  would suggest doing an UNION query thus multiple `select` statements each querying different table

if they have different columns use the `,` operator and give the table aliases and then select appropriately

```
select x.a,y.b,y.c from table(os_un_etcist('4815044')) as x, table(os_un_etcist('415175')) as y
```

P.S: This is based on my interpretation of OPs question.

Comment: Can you please show me sample code, parameters will be entered by user via a webpage, but can you just show me, how to do multiple select statements.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm and then you need to write code to build up this query for you

Comment: Thanks, it will be same columns, I will be selecting, but I will need to pass may be 30 parameter at once. I need better solution. I will read the you provided.

Comment: I dont think databases support querying multiple tables.. it screws up with the query plans and I have never seen it done before.. drop me a line here if you find something

Comment: ok, I will surely do that, what you suggested throw and error. `One or more errors occurred during processing of command. ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended at System.Data.OleDb. `